# How can I modify my inner join so that it only returns 1 row per item?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a table, `hs_book` that has column called `GENRE_ID`

I get the description of that genre from a table called `GENRE`

My subquery for column `Genre` :

```
SELECT *,
    Genre = (
        SELECT DESCRIPTION
        FROM GENRE
        WHERE GENRE_ID = (
            SELECT TOP 1 GENRE_ID 
            FROM BOOK_GENRES
            WHERE BOOK_ID = hs_book.BOOK_ID
            )
    )
FROM hs_book
```

When I execute this query, I get 525 books (which is correct).

At the request of a senior DBA, I am trying to convert it to a JOIN so I don't need the subquery, so I did this:

```
SELECT * FROM hs_book hsb
INNER JOIN BOOK_GENRES bg ON hsb.BOOK_ID = bg.BOOK_ID
```

When I run that, I get 541 results back, which is 16 more than the subquery.

After checking the data, I can see somehow, a few books have multiple `GENRE_IDs`.

Is there a way to modify my join so that I get only one genre back for each book?

Comment: When a book has multiple genres, what value are you therefore expecting? At the moment, in your query, you get an **arbitrary** one.

Comment: You can't make your join only return a single row. That is not how they work. But you could modify your query so you don't need the subquery.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1` has no `ORDER BY` so how do you know which one you will get?

Comment: Define "first". Remember tables in SQL have no ordering.

Comment: You could use an `APPLY` to be able to use a lateral join with a `TOP (1)`, but still, do you *want* that? If a book has multiple genres, why do you *not* want all the values?

Comment: So, again, define the "top" one. Alphabetically? By ID? Most "popular" (define popular). Something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the rows which have the Max value for a column for each distinct value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-for-a-column-for-each-distinct-value-of)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to ensure that `BOOK_GENRES` returns a single row per `BOOK_ID`.

- Either aggregate it

```sql
SELECT
  hsb.ID,
  hsb.Name,
  STRING_AGG(bg.Genre, ', ') Genre
FROM hs_book hsb
INNER JOIN BOOK_GENRES bg ON hsb.BOOK_ID = bg.BOOK_ID
GROUP BY
  hsb.ID,
  hsb.Name;
```

- Or pre-aggregate it in a derived table

```sql
SELECT
  hsb.ID,
  hsb.Name,
  bg.Genre
FROM hs_book hsb
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      bg.BOOK_ID,
      STRING_AGG(bg.Genre, ', ') Genre
    FROM BOOK_GENRES bg
    GROUP BY
      bg.BOOK_ID
) bg ON hsb.BOOK_ID = bg.BOOK_ID;
```

You can also do this with an `APPLY`.

```sql
SELECT
  hsb.ID,
  hsb.Name,
  bg.Genre
FROM hs_book hsb
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      STRING_AGG(bg.Genre, ', ') Genre
    FROM BOOK_GENRES bg
    WHERE hsb.BOOK_ID = bg.BOOK_ID
    GROUP BY
      ()
) bg;
```

- Or use `ROW_NUMBER` to filter it. If you don't care which order then use `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)`.

```sql
SELECT
  hsb.ID,
  hsb.Name,
  bg.Genre
FROM hs_book hsb
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      BG.BOOK_ID,
      bg.Genre,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bg.BOOK_ID ORDER BY bg.Genre) rn
    FROM BOOK_GENRES bg
) bg ON hsb.BOOK_ID = bg.BOOK_ID AND bg.rn = 1;
```

The first three options are likely all the same performance, as the compiler can usually convert between them.

The final one is likely similar to your original query.

Note that these have slightly different semantics than your original, as they use `INNER JOIN` and `CROSS APPLY`. You may want to switch to `LEFT JOIN` or `OUTER APPLY`.